# Convert dates in Python from a text file with text

Tags: python, date, awk, sed

I have a text file (with `utf-8` text) with lots of text and dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, with years ranging from 1970 to 2022. I want to read this file and convert the dates to `yyyy-mm-dd` format, while keeping all the text as it is. Do you know how to do it with Python? Or I don't mind using another tool (such as `awk`, `sed`) but as long as the rest of the file will not be affected.

Optionally, I want to search also for dates without leading zeros in the day or month, and convert them too. But first I want to display them (I'm not sure if there are such dates).

It's important not to convert other strings, so if the "year" is not from 1970 to 2022, don't convert the string.

I wrote this program but it needs debugging, I don't know how to write the `_repl` function properly.

```py
import re
import io


def _repl(s):
    x = s.split("/")
    if ((len(x) == 3) and (0 < int(x[0]) <= 31) and (0 < int(x[1]) <= 12) and (1970 <= int(x[2]) <= 2022)):
        return "{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}".format(int(x[2]), int(x[1]), int(x[0]))
    return x


with io.open("1.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    b = f.readlines()

c = list()
for line in b:
    _line = ""
    while (not (_line == line)):
        # _line = re.sub(pattern=r'([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})', repl=_repl, string=line)
        _line = re.sub(pattern=r'([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})', repl=_repl, string=line)
    c.append(_line)

with io.open('2.txt', mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in c:
        f.write("{}".format(line))
```

Comment: I could be missing something, but would it not be possible to just split the string and convert to the desired format?

Comment: @Leaderboard The dates don't have to be in separate words, they might contain letters before them or after them.

Comment: So you mean something like "test12/12/1988testing" should be converted to "test1988-12-12testing"?

Comment: @Leaderboard Yes, but actually this makes more sense in Hebrew. For example, convert "ב-10/10/1999" to "ב-1999-10-10".

Comment: I would recommend using some generic regex to extract the dates from the text, like `r'([0-9][0-9])\/([0-1][0-9])\/([1-2][9|0][0-9][0-9])'`, store its position (or just replace this pattern afterwards) and then parse it with a `strptime()` method. Check if day/month/year properties pass your validation and then return back to string with `strftime()` in your desired format.

Comment: can we have an example text?

Answer (score 1):

`repl` function gets as its' single argument match object, consider following simple example

```
import re

def repl(m):
    day, month, year = m.groups()
    return '-'.join([year, month, day]) if 1970 <= int(year) <= 2022 else m.group()

text1 = "Date 01/01/1901 and 01/01/3001 are outside range"
text2 = "Year 2000 should not be changed"
text3 = "Date 01/12/1970 shall be changed"
print(re.sub(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', repl, text1))
print(re.sub(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', repl, text2))
print(re.sub(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', repl, text3))
```

output

```
Date 01/01/1901 and 01/01/3001 are outside range
Year 2000 should not be changed
Date 1970-12-01 shall be changed
```

Explanation: I use argument unpacking to get day, month, year, then I check if year (as numerical value) is inside range of [1970,2022] if yes I do create `-`-sheared year, month, day otherwise I left what was matched as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Daweo for your answer. I just changed it a bit to accept also dates without leading zeros in the day or the month.

This is my program:

```py
import re
import io


def _repl(m):
    day, month, year = m.groups()
    if ((0 < int(day) <= 31) and (0 < int(month) <= 12) and (1970 <= int(year) <= 2022)):
        return "{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}".format(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    else:
        return m.group()


with io.open("1.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    b = f.readlines()

c = list()
for line in b:
    _line = re.sub(pattern=r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', repl=_repl, string=line)
    c.append(_line)

with io.open('2.txt', mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in c:
        f.write("{}".format(line))
```

Here are some texts for testing:

```py
text1 = "Date 01/01/1901 and 01/01/3001 are outside range"
text2 = "Year 2000 should not be changed"
text3 = "Date 01/12/1970 shall be changed"
text4 = "'Date' 99/99/1970 should not be changed"
text5 = "'Date' 13/13/1970 should not be changed"
text6 = "Date 1/2/1970 shall be changed"
text7 = "Dates 01/12/1972,04/11/2022 shall be changed"
print(re.sub(pattern=r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', repl=_repl, string=text1))
print(re.sub(pattern=r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', repl=_repl, string=text2))
print(re.sub(pattern=r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', repl=_repl, string=text3))
print(re.sub(pattern=r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', repl=_repl, string=text4))
print(re.sub(pattern=r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', repl=_repl, string=text5))
print(re.sub(pattern=r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', repl=_repl, string=text6))
print(re.sub(pattern=r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', repl=_repl, string=text7))
```

And the output is:

```py
Date 01/01/1901 and 01/01/3001 are outside range
Year 2000 should not be changed
Date 1970-12-01 shall be changed
'Date' 99/99/1970 should not be changed
'Date' 13/13/1970 should not be changed
Date 1970-02-01 shall be changed
Dates 1972-12-01,2022-11-04 shall be changed
```